# Delete item from list Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic to do list app.
I'm working on a delete function where you click the delete button and it will delete the list item, but have I'm having problems and can't figure it out.
the delete button shows, but when you click it nothing happens.

HTML:

```
 <ion-view view-title="To-Do">
  <ion-content class="padding">



    <!-- http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#bar-inputs -->
    <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon  placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" placeholder="Enter Task Here">
      </label>
      <button class="button ion-ios-plus-outline" ng-click="addItem(item)">

      </button>
    </div>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate" ng-repeat="item in items" >
        <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive ion-trash-a" ng-click="remove($index)"></ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller:

```
 .controller('ShortTermCtrl', function($scope, Task) {

  $scope.data = Task.data;


  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.item = {};

  $scope.addItem = function (item) {
    $scope.items.push(item);
    $scope.item = {name: ""};

  };

  $scope.removeItem = function(index){
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  };


})
```

Comment: Change function name from `remove` to `removeItem`.

Comment: thanks so much! that worked , problem was that I had been looking at the code so long that i just didnt see it ! thanks

Comment: do you want to change your comment to an answer so I can mark it as solved/ answer for other people to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong function name in view. Change it from `remove` to `removeItem`:

```
<ion-option-button class="button-assertive ion-trash-a" ng-click="removeItem($index)"></ion-option-button>
```

Comment: I got my code for the add & delete function here:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88039/discussion-between-mudasser-ajaz-and-rredcat and @Alexander Man pointed out my mistake, that I had named my function in the html file wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for ng-repeat use

```
ng-repeat='(index, item) in items'
```

to keep track of the index of every item, and pass the index to the remove function

```
ng-click="removeItem({{index}})"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your codexample, you commented out the remove(task) function, you need to target the removeItem(index) function in your HTML

```
<ion-option-button class="button-assertive ion-trash-a" ng-click="removeItem(1)">
```

Instead of a static index number, provide the items/index itself to a generic function, then delete that array item, like so:

```
 $scope.removeItem = function(items, index){
  items.splice(index, 1);
 };
```

Your HTML will look like so:

```
<ion-option-button class="button-assertive ion-trash-a" ng-click="removeItem(items, $index)">
```

The $index is automatically exposed to your ng-repeat scope among other useful properties, you can read more in the docs of ng-repeat: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat